# Auto sorting Spreadsheet

Tags: sorting, google-sheets

I am new to spreadsheets. I am using it as my backend. I want the new responses to b in the first row, i.e. the whole table should be sorted in the descending order of timestamp. In column 1 I have a time stamp. I have columns till J. So how to sort the table automatically so that whenever the new responses come the table is auto sorted. I did check [this](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/7211/how-can-i-make-some-data-on-a-google-spreadsheet-auto-sorting).
But I don't understand how to apply data formula to my spreadsheet.

Comment: Is this Excel or Google Sheets?  Did you read through all of the answers in the reference you gave?  It looks like the last one is what you need.

Comment: its google spreadsheets

Comment: You need to remove the Excel Tag from your post then.  And the last posting on the reference you gave does fit.

Comment: A google spreadsheet having column from a to J..I need to sort it based on timestamp which is present in column A..If understand that formula can u please conver it to my case ..My sheet name is Datakk (Responce11)

Comment: Sorry to bug u..But i dont knw anything about it ..i tried learning but i didnt understand anything...

Comment: Same idea..  Just change it to fit..  `=QUERY(A1:J200,"SELECT * ORDER BY A") `

Comment: circular dependency error !!

Comment: because that goes on another sheet. with proper reference to the other sheet as in sheet1!a1:j200.

Answer (score 1):

I think either of these should work for you:

`=SORT('Datakk (Responce11)'!A2:J,1,0)`

`=QUERY('Datakk (Responce11)'!A2:J,"order by A desc")`

Comment: where should i put this

Comment: add in an additional sheet to your response workbook and paste the formula into cell A1